# jqplot not displaying graph when using a custom tickRenderer (CanvasAxisTickRenderer)

Tags: jqplot

I have a complex graph (using highlighter.js, dateAxisRenderer.js, canvasOverlay.js, and enhancedLegendRenderer.js)
I want to add a label to the y axis (rotated in 90 degrees)
I included jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js file and this is what i added to the cose:

```
yaxis: {
    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
    angle: 90,
    label: "y axis label"
}
```

When adding this, the whole graph disappear.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem remains if you modify **angle: 90** by :

```
tickOptions: { angle:90 }
```

An other option is to modify **angle: 90** by :

```
angle: -90
```

as accepted values for angle may goes from -90 to 89.
Is a debug tool like Firebug says something?

**Edit :** Try to combine both if you still have your problem